# UIButton smooth touch effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton

I am trying to implement `UIButton's` smooth touch effect like we use calculator in our `iPhone` devices. However i have tried some code in `Objective c` and `Swift` as well but found the same result which is not up to the desire.

Tried code:

```
@IBAction func someAction(sender: UIButton){
    button.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
}
```

---

```
// using extension
extension UIButton {
    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControlState) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
        let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, forState: forState)
    }}
```

**Explanation:** the above code works fine as i need but the applied effect is not so smooth. In fact when i touch button it takes a nano second to apply background image on it and when i release touch the background image disappear suddenly.

I also tried this in `Objective c` using `TouchUpInside` and `TouchDown` event but result found same.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The slow part is the CoreGraphics processing in the button extension. why can't u just use UIButton setBackgroundColor to change the color?

Comment: @GeneCode its not about changing color, it is about apply effect over button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Complete solution:** using `CABasicAnimation` and adding a layer over button.

```
@IBAction func someAction(sender: UIButton){
   let colorAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
   colorAnimation.fromValue = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
   colorAnimation.duration = 1  // animation duration
   // colorAnimation.autoreverses = true // optional in my case 
   // colorAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX // optional in my case 
   sender.layer.addAnimation(colorAnimation, forKey: "ColorPulse")
}
```

Reference: as user iOS_devloper [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41115485/4003548).

Answer (score 1):

Create subclass of UIButton and override highlighted property:

```
override var highlighted: Bool {
        get {
            return super.highlighted
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            }
            else {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            }
            super.highlighted = newValue
        }
    }
```

Comment: and if you want some kind of animation while changing background color from highlighted to normal ..you can add animation while changing background color  -- let colorAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
colorAnimation.fromValue = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
colorAnimation.toValue = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
colorAnimation.duration = 1
colorAnimation.autoreverses = true
colorAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX
self.layer.addAnimation(colorAnimation, forKey: "ColorPulse")

Answer (score -2):

Assign property for your button and put this code in viewDidLoad.

```
yourButton.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

The problem was you set it only when user press. This code takes time as it uses CoreGraphics. You can immediately set the background img for highlighted state in viewdidload and it will stay there and be called immediately as u tap the button.

Comment: wait a while, let me apply this.

Comment: you code working fine as i am doing but the ques is still remain as it is.

Comment: setting background color don't have "forState:" property. Please Change your answer.

Comment: I cannot change the answer since the property existed in 2016 and the code refers to that particular version of iOS